# Understanding why the family of sets is not an algebra

Tags: real-analysis, abstract-algebra, measure-theory

Let $\mathcal{F} = \{A \subseteq \Omega: |A| \text{ is even} \}$ be a family of sets of $\Omega$ = $\{1, 2, 3, ..., 2n \}$ for some $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and let $\Omega \in \mathcal{F}$. I am able to show that this family of sets satisfies the following two properties:

1. Closed under complements
2. Closed under finite disjoint unions

However, I want to show that it is not an algebra. Specifically I want to show that it is $\textbf{not}$ closed under finite unions.

I get lost when trying to show that it is not closed under finite unions because I can't think of a case where closed under disjoint unions $\nRightarrow$ closed under unions.

edit:

I should specify that an algebra satisfies the following properties:

1. $\Omega$ $\in$ $\mathcal{F}$
2. Closed under complements
3. Closed under finite unions

Thanks for the help.

Comment: I seem to be missing something because you talk about a $\sigma$-algebra on the set $\{1,2, \dots, 2n\}$ but nowhere you mention explicitely what this $\sigma$-algebra is?

Comment: No, I am not talking about a $\sigma$-algebra just a family of sets that satisfy properties specified above.

Comment: But for example the power set of $\Omega$ is a \sigma$-algebra that is closed under finite unions hence also under disjoint finite unions. So unless you mention the explicit example you are considering, we can't help.

Comment: I forgot to put in the family of sets I was considering. I see the problem now. My apologies I will edit.

Comment: I added an answer below. Feel free to ask for clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume $n \geq 2$ (if $n=1$, then $\mathcal{F}= \{\emptyset, \{1,2\}\}$ is closed under finite unions).

The union $\{1,2,3\}=\{1,2\}\cup \{2,3\}$ is not in $\mathcal{F}$ so $\mathcal{F}$ is not closed under finite unions.

Comment: Yes, that was silly of me ... thank you for help :)

Comment: You are welcome!